# Ubuntu boot problem - free initramfs and switch to another root fs

Tags: linux, ubuntu

We are using Ubuntu 20.04 operating system running on Xen infrastructure. But when I turned on the server after the power went out, I encountered the following errors. I tried `e2fsck`, etc. but no solution.

How can I overcome this problem?

```
free initramfs and switch to another root fs: 
chroot to NEW_ROOT, delete all in /, move NEW_ROOT to /, execute NEW_INIT. PID must be 1. NEW_ROOT must be a mountpoint.
-c DEV reopen stdio to DEV after switch
-d CAPS drop capabilities
-n Dry run
BusyBox v1.30.1 ( ubuntu 1:1.30.1-4-ubuntu6.4) multi-call binary.
Usage run-init [-d CAP,CAP...] [-n] [-c CONSOLE_DEV] NEW_ROOT NEW_INIT [ARGS]
```

Also I had a separate disk, in case of readonly, no data can be written to the room that is plugged in.

Answer (score 0):

I installed a new VM and added the disk of the problematic VM. Then I fixed the problem using the following commands:

```
modprobe dm-mod
lvmdiskscan
lvscan
mke2fs -n /dev/xvdb3
dumpe2fs /dev/xvdb2 | grep superblock
e2fsck -b 98304 /dev/xvdb2
e2fsck -b 163840 /dev/xvdb2
e2fsck -b 229376 /dev/xvdb2
#lvm start
vgchange -ay ubuntu-vg
mkdir /disk1
mount /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv /disk1
#alternative read-only mount
mount -o ro,noload /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv /disk1
umount /disk1
#lvm stop
vgchange -an ubuntu-vg
vgs
lvmdisplay
vgdisplay
vgrename gREOvI-FNeY-TjPl-WcQv-WxXT-2afG-bV9MSc ubuntu-vg-test
```

Comment: Could you explain what you did over there?